# How to create keywords from an API generated list and look for them in Social Media using Python?

Tags: python, api, twitter, reddit, social-media

What I have to do is
Step 1: use the https://newsapi.org/ and Python to generate the top 10 daily news
Step 2: save keywords of these news and look for related tweets and posts on reddit in real time and save the related content automatically, also in real time

I am stuck on step 2

This is what I have so far

```
import requests
def topnews():
    query_params = {
        "source": "bbc-news",
        "sortBy": "top",
        "apiKey": "4dbc17e007ab436fb66416009dfb59a8"
    }
    url = " https://newsapi.org/v1/articles"
    res = requests.get(url, params=query_params)
    news = res.json()

    article = news["articles"]

    results = []

    for ar in article:
        results.append(ar["title"])

    for i in range(len(results)):
        print(i + 1, results[i])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    topnews()
```

Comment: The next steps would be: remove stop words from the titles to extract the keywords. Then use those keywords to find the relevant tweets or Reddit posts by using the APIs of Twitter (Streaming APIs for real-time) and Most probably something similar for Reddit.

Comment: How are you stuck exactly, what have you tried for "step 2"?